# hello i want to mine with minerd, i have the file, but i don't know the OPTIONS

Tags: bitcoin

i have ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.
i want to learn how to mine bitcoins.
when i execute the file i don't know the OPTIONS.

```
./minerd
```

./minerd: no URL supplied
Try `minerd --help' for more information.

[guide](http://doges.org/digging-coins/guide-on-mining-with-minerd-(cpu)/)

Comment: it's impossible to mine bitcoins with that guide since it's made for doggecoin!

Comment: I reccomend you to read the documentation of that command you are using (you can start with `minerd --help`), as this issue is not ubuntu-specific and neither ubuntu-related - you probably need to add some command line arguments when launching that program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The miner daemon called `minerd` (part of `pooler's cpuminer`) supports only virtual currencies based on *scrypt* or *SHA-256d*. It will work with *Litecoin* or with some special pools for indirect *Bitcoin* mining.
You can use the following syntax:

- HTTP mining pool:

  minerd --url=http://example.com:9332 --userpass=workerid:password
- STRATUM mining pool:

  minerd --url=stratum+tcp://example.com:3333 --userpass=workerid:password

The first parameter is the mining pool's URI with the corresponding port; you will obtain that information in the pool's website.
The second parameter is an optional user/pass combination: the worker ID is the **unique** name of an active miner daemon in the pool (chosen by you or assigned randomly from the pool's web portal) and the pass is a pass for the relative remote account.
Please note:

- Use mining software **only** on your computer.
  Do not try to use it on remote machines (for example VPS) because you *will* get banned for extreme bandwidth/resource consumption.
- It can be seen as a false positive by any antivirus, because some malware use it as a *payload*.

I *suggest* to mine alternative coins like Litecoin, because Bitcoin requires specialized hardware to be remunerative.
Please, **feel free to comment under here if you have more questions** and don't forget to press the left UP arrow and mark as favorite if I'm of any help.
Have a nice day.

Comment: [easy mining](https://www.easymining.eu/ltc/index.php?page=gettingstarted)